# Show that functional $f(x)$ is unbounded and norm $\|A\|=\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

Let  $(H;(\cdot|\cdot))$ be separable Hilbert space where $\dim$ $H=\infty$. We define norm $\|x\|=\sqrt{\langle x|x\rangle}$ and linear operator $A:H\to H$. Show that:

a) functional $f(x):=\langle Ax|a \rangle \in \mathbb{C}$ is unbounded and $\ker f$ is dense in $H$, when vector $a\notin \operatorname{dom} A^{*}$, $ A^{*}:H\to H$.

b) show that $\|A\|=\infty$.

I would ask for a draft proof or a solution because I don't know where to start.

Comment: I would suggest you look up the definition of $dom(A^\star)$, then it should be not too difficult. Also, $b.)$ is simply wrong, the correct question would be to ask "If $dom(A^\star) \neq H$, then $\Vert A \Vert = \infty.$

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add that assumption to b) thanks, I will try to figure it out

Comment: This need a lot of cleaning up. As-is, it's barely understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f$ is bounded then (by Riesz Theoem) there exists $y$ such that $\langle Ax , a \rangle =\langle x , y \rangle$ for  all $x$. By definition this means $a \in dom(A^{*})$ and $A^{*}a=y$. This is a  contradiction.  Hence $f$ is unbounded.

Now $ker f$ has co-dimension $1$. (This is true for  any non-zero linear functional). If $ker (f)$ is a proper subspace of $H$ then we would have the struct inclusions $\ker (f) \subset \overline {\ker (f)} \subset H$ but this contradicts the fact that co-dimension is $1$. Hence $ker (f)$ is dense. Of course $\|A\|=\infty$ becasue $A$ is unbounded.

Comment: Why we take that ker(f) has co-dimension 1?

Comment: @Michal Hint: if $f\neq 0$ then there exists $x_0$ such that $f(x_0) \neq 0$. For any $x$ we can find $c$ such that $f(x-cx_0)=0$ ($c=\frac {f(x)} {f(x_0)}$. So $x =cx_0+y$ where $y =x-cx_0 \in ker (f)$. Hence co-dimension of $ker (f)$ is $1$.